# Tomcat7 Compression JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, css, tomcat, tomcat7, http-compression

I've enabled compression using the following setting in my tomcat7 server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
compression="on"
compressionMinSize="2048"
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/json,text/javascript,text/css,text/plain,
application/javascript,application/xml,application/xml+xhtml"
/>
```

I've checked that compression is now switched on using: http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/

However, PageSpeed still reports that several CSS/JS files are not being compressed.
e.g. 
Compressing http://www.mysite.co.uk/css/bootstrap.css could save 109.5KiB (84% reduction).

Comment: I ended up using Apache HTTPD with pagespeed module

Comment: Thanks :)   I need a solution with Tomcat...

Answer (score 2):

Are all the CSS/JS files that are not compressed relatively large? Maybe those are sent by "sendfile" and thus avoid being compressed.

In the documentation:

> "Note: There is a tradeoff between using compression (saving your
>   bandwidth) and using the sendfile feature (saving your CPU cycles). If
>   the connector supports the sendfile feature, e.g. the NIO connector,
>   using sendfile will take precedence over compression. The symptoms
>   will be that static files greater that 48 Kb will be sent
>   uncompressed. You can turn off sendfile by setting useSendfile
>   attribute of the connector, as documented below, or change the
>   sendfile usage threshold in the configuration of the DefaultServlet in
>   the default conf/web.xml or in the web.xml of your web application."

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html

Set in your config:

```
useSendfile="false"
```

Comment: No I have the problem with smaller files as well. I've added that line anyway and also set compression="force" and I still get the same issue.